# pd.read_excel won't read 100% valid excel file by link

Tags: python, web, request, telegram-bot

I'm creating Telegram Bot that must download file from DropBox, read it, format it into text and send it to a user.

First take a look at *functions/read_file.py*

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

from math import isnan


def get_content_from_request(url: str, academic_year: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    if academic_year == "1":
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            try:
                data_frame = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(response.content), sheet_name="1 тиждень", skiprows=8, nrows=55, usecols="A:R")
                return data_frame
            except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
                print("The DataFrame is empty. Check if the sheet or data range is correct.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred while reading the Excel file: {str(e)}")
        else:
            print("Failed to download the file. Check the URL or network connection.")

        return data_frame


def parse_message(course: str, major: str, df: pd.DataFrame) -> str:
    print(df[df["Заняття"]])
    if course == '1':
        # if major in ["ГРС(ГО)",   "ПТ", "Т", "ХТ"]:
        #     pass

        major_data = (df[df["Заняття"].isin([i for i in range(9)])][f"11-{major}"])
        
        text_to_parse = []

        classes_counter = 1
        for sentence in major_data:
            if classes_counter == 1:
                temp = []

            if not(isinstance(sentence, (int, float)) and isnan(sentence)):
                temp.append(f"{classes_counter}. {sentence}")
                classes_counter += 1
            else:
                text_to_parse.append(temp)
                temp = []
                classes_counter = 1

        message_text = ""

        for sentence in text_to_parse:
            for j in sentence:
                if sentence != 0:
                    if j[0] == '1':
                        message_text += "\n"
                        
                message_text += f"\n{j}"

    return message_text
```

Functions above are used in *message handler*:

```
if course_number == '1️⃣':
        url = config("URL_FIRST_YEAR_SCHEDULE")
        data_frame = read_file.get_content_from_request(url, "1")
        message_to_send = read_file.parse_message('1️⃣', "ГРС(РО)", data_frame)
        message_to_send = formatting_text.format_class_number(message_to_send)
        
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"<b>1 ТИЖДЕНЬ</b>\n<b>11-{major}</b>{data_frame}", parse_mode="HTML")
```

*URL_FIRST_YEAR_SCHEDULE* in .env:
`URL_FIRST_YEAR_SCHEDULE  = https://www.dropbox.com/s/dl/jlxebjyrtc9f8vj/розклад%201%20курсу.xls`

Link is absolutely valid and the file contains all necessary rows/columns.
The problem is that `def get_content_from_request(url: str, academic_year: str) -> pd.DataFrame:` returns `Empty DataFrame` , yet it shouldn't be.

I have tested the file (downloaded from the link) by just putting him into working directory and reading it as a static one, and all worked fine, but in the case of sending a request and downloading it this doesn't work at all.
I expect the script to correctly fecth the file.